# Passing a unknown size matrix reference to a c function

Tags: c

I'm new to C(but starting to like it after a bit of the growing pains) but I'm having a bit of trouble sending a matrix.  I started building everything in my main function and it worked.
I created the list like this: `int list[sizeOfBuckets][30];` then added data and when I wanted to read it I did something like this:

```
    int x;
    int xx;
    for (x=0;x<sizeof(current_list) / sizeof(current_list[0]); x++) {
        printf("we are in the list \n");
        for (xx=0;xx<sizeof(current_list[x]) / sizeof(current_list[x][0]); xx++) {
            printf("item: %i \n", current_list[x][xx]);
        } 
    }
```

It worked fine, it would give me the contents of the matrix. But now I want to send it to a function but I'm having problems. I did some reading and learned that matrix's are not the same as sending arrays as C needs to know the dimensions beforehand but since I will have this dynamically changing I created two variables that monitor the sizes of both and I send them to an array(in my test I verified they are correct, list is list`[2][30]`).  Here's my function:

```
void process_list(int **current_list, int num_of_rows, int num_items_in_row) {
    printf("hello from function \n");
    //test the list
    int x;
    int xx;
    for (x=0;x<num_of_rows; x++) {
        printf("we are in the list \n");
        for (xx=0;xx<num_items_in_row; xx++) {
            printf("item: %i \n", current_list[x][xx]);
        } 
    }
}
```

It doesn't work for me. It simply prints out `we are in the list` and not the actual items(from the for loop below) as I would expect. When I compile with GCC I get the following warning:

```
./learningC.c: In function ‘main’:
./learningC.c:169: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘process_list’ from incompatible pointer type
```

I'm wondering what am I doing wrong?  If it helps, I don't need to modify the array, I just need to contents sent to the function and then my function will output a different result.

Update: Here's the matrix I'm sending:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 4],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4],
```

Here's the expected result:

```
hello from function 
we are in the list 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 2 
item: 2 
item: 2 
item: 4 
we are in the list 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 1 
item: 1 
item: 2 
item: 2 
item: 4 
we are in the list 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 0 
item: 1 
item: 2 
item: 1 
item: 2 
item: 4
```

Comment: Show line 169 where you are passing the array?

Comment: @MikeKwan its simply: `process_list(list, count, countListItem);`the variable list is the matrix as shown above, count is the number of rows, and countListItem is the number of items per row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a modern C compiler, starting with C99 would do, you can pass a matrix with variable lengths (technical term is "VLA") just like this

```
void process_list(size_t num_of_rows, size_t num_items_in_row, int current_list[num_of_rows][num_items_in_row]) {
... access the elements as current_list[i][j] here ...
}
```

Just watch that you have the sizes before the array, such that they are known in the declaration of the array parameter.

BTW, your attempt to do it with `**` is not correct at all. A 2D matrix and an array of pointers are really different things.

Comment: Thanks this is much easier. Didn't know I can pass the variable while passing the variables to the function. C just went up a notch in my books(its now at notch 1).

Comment: sorry, one more question.  I get warnings when I compile using size_t because its expecting an int. If I change it to int it works fine, is there any impact in this case of not using size_t? Numbers will def be within int range(max matrix size will be 1000 but most likely just 100 or so).

Comment: @Error_404, what is the error that you encounter? Perhaps you are just missing the `stddef.h` header file?

Answer (score 2):

An n dimensional array is still an array of 1 dimensional memory space. So use only a pointer, not a pointer to pointer.

```
void process_list(int *current_list, int num_of_rows, int num_items_in_row) {
    printf("hello from function \n");
    //test the list
    int x;
    int xx;
    for (x=0;x<num_of_rows; x++) {
        printf("we are in the list \n");
        for (xx=0;xx<num_items_in_row; xx++) {
            printf("item: %i \n", current_list[x*num_items_in_row + xx]); % previously it was x*num_of_rows + xx
        } 
    }
}
```

I also changed the way to access elements.
Now you must make the function call like that:

```
process_list(*current_list,3,3);
```

Comment: When I do that I get the same warning as above but I get an error `error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer` on the line `printf("item: %i \n", current_list[x][xx]);`

Comment: Thanks, but the result is not exactly correct..The first row prints fine, then the second row is shifted by two items, and the 3rd row is shifted by 2 more items(so its 4 items off). Actually the results are not even correct because the values in the matrix are not changing, its the same values as the first row but being shifted/repeated.

Comment: did you call the function with parameters of "3,3"? I'm testing now and will give you the feedback.

Comment: I updated the question to show an example of the data and expected output.  I'm very new to C so sorry if I'm wrong but when I printed the matrix successfully in my main function I did it by doing list[x][xx], I haven't tried multiplying the values successfully.

Comment: no using my program, it checks the size and the size in this case is 3, 30 so those are the values that were sent to the function. I can modify my data and test 3, 3 if you would like.

Comment: @Error_404 Ah my mistake, I must have used not `num_of_rows` but `num_items_in_row` for indexing. Updating the code now.

Comment: There is no need to do such index calculations as they are proposed here yourself if you have a modern C compiler. C can do all of this for you directly. Please see my answer.

Comment: @JensGustedt I know VLA very well, but majority of my work was not in C99 because of the compiler that I'm using.

Comment: +1 your solution works thanks.  I wish I could accept both answers but I think Jens answer is a lot simpler and easier for me to grasp(but I will study arrays more because your way of multiplying the location is interesting and kind of similar to cuda c). Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few ways of passing 2D arrays. I shall first go over a few examples of these then point out the fundamental error in your code:

```
/*
 * Array with empty first dimension.
 * Note the y value passed is redundant in this case.
 */
void process_matrix(int matrix[][4], int x, int y)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
            printf("[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j, matrix[i][j]);
        }

        puts("");
    }
}
```

This function takes in an array with an empty first dimension. This allows the unknown size that you state to be passed in. The `y` is redundant in this case because we can get it back out using something a macro such as `ARRAY_SIZE`.

```
/*
 * Pointer to array with explicitly specified second dimension.
 * Again the y value passed is redundant in this case.
 */
void process_matrix2(int (* matrix)[4], int x, int y)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
            printf("[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j, matrix[i][j]);
        }

        puts("");
    }
}
```

This is a pointer to an array where the second dimension is explicitly specified. Note the bracketing which is very important in this case. The same code without brackets is still valid C but means something entirely different. By a similar argument as above, the `y` parameter is redundant.

```
/*
 * Both dimensions known.
 * Note the x and y value passed are both redundant in this case.
 */
void process_matrix3(int matrix[2][4], int x, int y)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
            printf("[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j, matrix[i][j]);
        }

        puts("");
    }
}
```

This case might not be applicable for you but is here for completeness. If both dimensions are known, they can be specified as part of the function prototype. By similar arguments as above, `x` and `y` are redundant here.

The above functions can be tested with this code (make sure to compile with `-std=c99`):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int matrix[2][4] = {{1,2,3,4}, {8,7,6,5}};

    process_matrix(matrix, 2, 4);
    process_matrix2(matrix, 2, 4);
    process_matrix3(matrix, 2, 4);
    process_matrix4(matrix, 2, 4);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Back to your original code, the problem you have is that a double pointer can't be used as a 2D array. To quote from [this article](http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/languages/fortran/append-c.html), which you should certainly read:

> ...it is wrong to declare:  "int **mat" and then use "mat" as a 2D
>   array. These are two very different data-types and using them you
>   access different locations in memory. On a good machine (e.g. VAX/VMS)
>   this mistake aborts the program with a "memory access violation"
>   error.
>
> This mistake is common because it is easy to forget that the decay
>   convention mustn't be applied recursively (more than once) to the same
>   array, so a 2D array is NOT equivalent to a double pointer.   A
>   "pointer to pointer of T" can't serve as a "2D array of T". The 2D
>   array is "equivalent" to a "pointer to row of T", and this is very
>   different from "pointer to pointer of T".

The article shows a few more methods of passing a 2D array which I don't show such as doing it by flattening the array, which is what [Seçkin Savaşçı](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10874415/712358) is trying to show.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mike, but can I do it in a way so I won't have to hardcode specific size numbers in my code?  I plan to change things around a bit and the array is actually coming from a file I'm parsing, so I'm worried if I hardcode a size and something changes then my code breaks.  I saw examples like mine where people figured out the size during runtime and passed it to the function but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Yep, check the link I posted. Specifically look at `func4`. The numbers they hardcode there can be passed in. If you can't get it working, say so here and I'll write a small example.

Answer (score 1):

There are some subtle distinctions between statically allocated multi-dimensional arrays in C and dynamically allocated ones, and I'm not sure if I remember them accurately. That said, I think the correct type of your matrix is actually a pointer to a one-dimensional 30-element integer array. Try altering your function declaration to read: `void process_list(int current_list[][30], int num_of_rows, int num_items_in_row)`, or perhaps `void process_list(int *current_list[30], int num_of_rows, int num_items_in_row)`.

Comment: I think that will work but what if I don't know the size in advance? in your case I'm hardcoding it in the code. I want to pass dynamic sizes to the function.

Comment: If you want to be able to resize the rows, then you should really allocate the memory dynamically from the start with `malloc()`, in which case you actually could have a proper `int **` type with the expected behavior.

Comment: I don't want to resize the rows(they will stay the same), I just don't know at compile time their size since its coming from an external source.

Comment: Well, depending on the source of the row length, it might be possible to just define a preprocessor constant with a default value and (optionally) alter it at compile time with an argument to the compiler. If that's not feasible, then I advise using dynamic allocation; if you don't have advance knowledge of the dimensions that your data will occupy, then static array allocation is just not suitable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm all for treating static arrays as objects vs. pointers.
However in the cases when it's about remedies to an existing code, some C casting trickery could be applied [carefully].

In your original example to pass a static array to process_list function, one may do:

```
int **arrptr;
int static_arr[3][4] = {...};  /* init static array */
...
*arrptr = (int *)&static_arr;    /* put the static_arr address into arrptr */

process_list(arrptr, num_rows,num_cols);
```

This effectively treats the static array as if it were malloc'ed, that is the pointer arrptr contains *reference* to memory address of static_arr, instead of the actual address, which is assigned at compile-time.

NOTE:I'm not advocating such technique, and if applied in code, some comments about the cast intent should be supplied. Otherwise someone may unknowingly try to "free" such pointer, also scoping issues etc.